# How to use a bucklescript library with rtop in an esy project?

Tags: ocaml, reason, bucklescript, utop, esy

I am attempting to use rtop as repl on an esy project.

In order to do so, I have added `"@esy-ocaml/rtop":"*"` to the `devDependencies` section of my package.json file, and tried to start rtop with `esy rtop`:

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "reason-react": ">=0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bs-platform": "^4.0.14",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8",
    "@esy-ocaml/rtop":"*"
  }
}
```

however, I am unable to load my components:

```
→ esy rtop
Reason # #use "./src/Component1.re";
File "./src/Component1.re", line 2, characters 5-16:
Error: Unbound module ReasonReact

Reason # #require "reason-react";
No such package: reason-react

Reason # #require "react";

Reason #
```

but, as you can see I am able to load React, whatever that means...

Well, how can I use rtop as my project repl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also [asked this in reasonml.chat](https://reasonml.chat/t/how-to-use-rtop-in-an-esy-project-repl/1373/2) and the answer was as follows

> Esy doesn’t magically make bs-platform works with native toolings.
>
> rtop is exclusively for native only and can’t be use in a bucklescript project